# Can i switch gdb client on XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos

How can I switch to use a different gdb client in Xcode on MACOS? Or if this is possible at all?

Thank you.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below please.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "different gdb client in Xcode." What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean switch to a different debugger GUI that uses gdb internally?  ddd is [available](http://ddd.darwinports.com/) for OS X so it's possible that there may also be others.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to go to the Product menu,
then select Scheme->Edit Scheme.

There you can change your debugger to be GDB instead of LLDB