# How can I use a different GDB in XCode?

Tags: xcode, gdb, fink

Similar questions are:

[How to specify which GDB I can use in XCode on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668069/how-to-specify-which-gdb-i-can-use-in-xcode-on-macos)

and

[Can i switch gdb client on XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905669/can-i-switch-gdb-client-on-xcode?rq=1)

The former refers to a document which is out of date and appears to not work for XCode 3.2.6 and the latter question was never really answered.

So does anyone know how I can use a different version of GDB, namely the one obtained with fink, fsf-gdb (GDB 7.4.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not work.  gdb and Xcode use the "mi" text-based protocol for communication and Apple has extended the mi interface in a number of ways over the years for Xcode's benefit.  Most of these changes never made it back upstream to mainline FSF gdb -- or those that did, were implemented in a different way.  Getting Xcode to run a different gdb is not the tricky bit - the tricky bit is that they won't work together.

I haven't tested a modern gdb and Xcode but I really don't think it will work.

If you haven't tried the lldb debugger recently, give it a shot.  The version in Xcode 4.5 is pretty solid.  Apple is actively supporting and developing this debugger now, if you're working on Mac OS X you'll be happier if you can adopt lldb for your workflow.  There is a gdb/lldb command cheatsheet at http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html which will show the equivalent lldb command for various gdb commands.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

But does LLDB support Fortran? A quick glance on their webpage (http://lldb.llvm.org/index.html) suggests that's not the case.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, not yet.  I don't think anyone currently working on lldb works with Fortran so it's unlikely to be added soon unless someone properly motivated steps up.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks for the informative answer about the "mi" protocol.